# How to prevent AIR application from jerking around while dragging?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I've created an AIR application and it seems to be working fine but when I drag the title bar to move the native window it shakes violently and have seizures while it's dragging about.

FYI It does eventually end up where I want it to be when I stop moving the mouse.

I'm using Flex 4.6 and AIR 3.6 on Mac OSX 10.10.5. It's a `s:WindowedApplication` I'm also using the DragManager on a list in part of the application if that matters but it is not enabled until the user clicks into the list and moves more than a certain number of pixels.

Here is my descriptor file minus name and version info:

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.6">
    <initialWindow>
        <autoOrients>false</autoOrients>
        <fullScreen>false</fullScreen>
        <visible>false</visible>
    </initialWindow>
</application>
```

On initialize I run this:

```
protected function initializeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void {

    width = Capabilities.screenResolutionX * .96;
    height = Capabilities.screenResolutionY * .9;

    nativeWindow.x = (Screen.mainScreen.bounds.width - width)/2;
    nativeWindow.y = (Screen.mainScreen.bounds.height - height)/2;

}
```

**UPDATE:**
I removed the main view component so it is an empty application and it drags around smoothly.

**UPDATE 2:**
I added the main view back in and dragged around step by step along the way. It appears to start happening when I've loaded a second Application (called a sub application) into the main application. I'm not sure though.

Comment: Typo: It should be corrected.

Comment: I've never seen this behavior. Can you reproduce it with a simple example?

Comment: I have not seen this either. I'm using newer versions of Air and Flex but not not remember anything like that in the older versions. BTW: Which OS (and version) is this happening on? Custom Skin on the Window? Window Chrome settings?

Comment: I've had this kind of behavior when the position of a DisplayObject alters the "bounds" of its parent.  Basically, if you move something that is part of another object's bounds, those bounds will change, and the width and height will no longer be reliable "center" points.  This might not be your problem, but the symptoms are identical.  You might try saving the Screen.mainScreen.bounds.width/height in variables and use those values during the interaction.

Comment: There are numerous places where I have width height 100%. I'll try setting fixed sizes in a few places and see if that helps. So as I'm moving it something is resizing while something else is trying to center itself? I use horizontal and vertical center a lot. I'll try fixed positions as well. It's a funny app. There's something else that is going on at the same time, if I'm not online most of the panels and text disappears. So it's been on my to do list to take everything off and add them back piece by piece.

Comment: I noticed it happening in a number of my applications! It appears to be a way that I'm developing apps. I place a component inside the application file. The problem is part of AIR I think. I'll add the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

This happens in numerous number of my applications. It is probably because I have a component inside my application file set to size to 100% of the application. But I have not verified this on all my apps.

The solution is to resize the AIR app. After I resize it it works fine. I can drag it around and it works as expected. I think this is an AIR bug.